# is there any risk of system failure when placing temp folders in a volatile ramdisk?

Tags: windows, ssd, ramdisk, temporary-files

There is many info about moving temp folder to a ramdisk is a good idea to increase the SSD life.

So, I tested it with my user temp folder and I have no problems, even the ramdisk is volatile.

But I'm didn't want to do this with the c:\windows\temp folder because that is the temp folder where system temp files are located, so, I thought that could cause system crashes or instability.

So, it is safe?

Comment: Your biggest issue would be if your system lost power while it was writing.  However, if you lose power, you can't use your system anyway.  So for temp file no problems.

Comment: You would be way better off moving the swap file to another drive as it generates 10x-100x more writes than your temp folders.  Depending on how much of your RAM is in use.  Windows also drops stuff to the swap file when it reaches a certain age, so you don't even need to run out of RAM before it does that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest You **not** doing this.

The temp files are not necessary for your system to run properly and it is fine to delete them sometimes.

**But**

The temp folder is often used for installing new software that sometimes require restarting the computer before it can continue the installation. If You restart your PC the ramdisk's data is lost and if the program that You are trying to install had some data in the temp file, the installation will not be completed.

If You want to make your SSD write less, You should change the default path of the temp files to a HDD after [this guide](http://www.askvg.com/where-does-windows-store-temporary-files-and-how-to-change-temp-folder-location/)